# I unable to open the exact URL from Firefox browser using Selenium webdriver. Can anyone help me?

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

[Here I have attached the console error report.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldZ1I.png)

I tried creating new profile and tried the same. Still it goes to [this](https://www.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/windows-10/welcome/?utm_source=firefox-browser&utm_medium=firefox-browser&utm_content=firstrun) link.

And not opening the site which i mentioned in `driver.navigate().to();`

Kindly drop your suggestions

Comment: Please add the screenshots to the question itself so it is easier to help you. Could you also add the code so we can see what you are trying to do?

Comment: WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.co.in");
String actual = driver.getTitle();
String expected = "Google Home Page";

if(actual.equalsIgnoreCase(expected))
 System.out.println("PASS");

else System.out.println("FAILS");
 
driver.close();

Comment: Tell me versions of Selenium jars and Firefox

Comment: Selenium version ==>  selenium-java-2.53.0

Firefox version   ==> 48.0b1    

Kindly check it @kishan

Comment: try with old firefox once..may be 45

Comment: Try 47 version of firefox.

Comment: Tried all versions , no changes

Comment: If your `Firefox version >=47` try with `MarionetteDriver`...follow this link..https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? Please read the help topics on how to ask a good question. You need to research your own issue, find code samples, etc. and write your own code to solve the issue. If you do all that and still can't figure it out, then come back and edit your question and add notes from the research you did, the code you have tried, and what the result was... any error messages, etc.

Comment: Try this `driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.co.in");`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
driver.navigate().to("http://google.co.in");
```

or

```
driver.get("http://google.co.in");
```

You need to give the URL with Proper Protocol.

Comment: I think URL is correct. But it is not navigating to requested URL. It stays in this below page

https://www.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/windows-10/welcome/?utm_source=firefox-browser&utm_medium=firefox-browser&utm_content=firstrun

Answer (score 0):

Use Firefox version 47.0.1 and selenium version 2.53.1
These are the latest compatible